# Ruby - split string made up of emails at space or comma

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I'm working with an instance method inside a class that needs to take in a string of emails and separate them at either a comma OR a space.

I keep getting one or the other to pass, but can't make it so that both the comma and space pass together. I'm trying with regex.

Thanks for your help!

```
def parse
  @emails.split(/,\s/)
end
```

example of emails list string: xyz@yahoo.com, blablabla@gmail.com luliluli@msn.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), denoted by `[]`.

```
@emails.split(/[,\s]+/)
```

The `[]` say to match any character in that set. The `+` is there because you want to treat multiple spaces between emails as a single separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
@emails.split(/\s|,/) will work // is for multiple and | is to say or
```

Comment: if you want multiple spaces, @Schwern 's solution works

Comment: If you want multiple spaces, but a single comma, use `/\s+|,/`.

Comment: @Schwern ya sorry

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.